# Access Docker Container from project registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So I have my docker image uploaded to my projects registry. I can navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/ and I see my Image listed there.

Now I want to run a VM on this project and on this one use docker to run this very image.

This is the command within my VM:

```
sudo /usr/bin/docker run eu.gcr.io/my-project-name/example001
```

The response is:

```
Unable to find image 'eu.gcr.io/.../example001:latest' locally
/usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this op
eration, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.goo
gle.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication.
See '/usr/bin/docker run --help'.
```

Please see the image attached. I can list my images if I define "eu.gcr.io/..." as my project path. However the machine seems to run on ".gcr.io" so therefor not able to access my image? How would I fix this - and why is my image on "eu.gcr.io" and the machine on ".gcr.io", I cant find a method to change this (either move the image to gcr.io or move the machine to, eu.gcr.io). However I'm not sure if this is the issue.

Maybe it is an authentication issue with docker?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VM basically cannot be on ".gcr.io", it can run in non-European region/zone, but it shouldn't be a problem.

From GCP access control point of view registry is just a bucket.
So I believe first thing you need to check is that VM has access to Google Cloud Storage.
With gcloud:

```
gcloud compute instances describe <instance-name>
```

check if VM has scope to read from devstorage:

```
serviceAccounts:
- email: ...-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  scopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
  - ...
```

This scope should be in place to read from registry:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only

If you don't have such scope on VM, but have there gcloud configured, you can use gcloud as credential helper:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

as stated in doc you referred: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#gcloud_as_a_docker_credential_helper

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/900026/gcp-no-access-to-container-registry-from-compute-engine

It is the docker command which needs the authorization. Not the hostname (eu.gcr.io) is the issue here. I used 'gcloud docker -- pull ...' command to get the image from the repository to use within my VM.

Answer (score 0):

after you create linux VM on GCP, SSH to it, you have to install Google SDK [1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives) using Cloud SDK with scripts][1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives) or manually.

If you are running Ubuntu follow the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get)  if you are installing with  Red Hat or CentOS follow the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-yum) after finishing the Google SDK you have to Run gcloud init to initialize the SDK, just open a terminal and tape [gcloud init] you have to configure your profile. after that you have to install Docker

- sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce
- sudo systemctl start docker

You need to have access to the registries which you will be pushing to and pulling from.

Configured Docker to use gcloud as a credential helper. To use [gcloud as the crediential helper](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling), run the command:

- gcloud auth configure-docker

After that you can pull or push images on your registry using the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/docker) with the docker as shown below:

Push: gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/google-containers/example-image:latest

pull: gcloud docker -- pull gcr.io/google-containers/example-image:latest